# How to get the current cgroup ID from C/C++?

Tags: system-calls, cgroups, ebpf

The [eBPF helper functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) define `bpf_get_current_cgroup_id` for eBPF programs, which does the obvious thing

```
u64 bpf_get_current_cgroup_id(void)

        Return A 64-bit integer containing the current cgroup id
               based on the cgroup within which the current task
               is running.
```

However I can't find an equivalent system call (something similar to [getpid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getppid.2.html)) that I can use in a regular old C program

Am I just completely missing the relevant function? Or does userspace need to do something different to get the cgroup ID for the current task?

Comment: I'm not sure that information is exposed to userspace. What are you trying to do with those IDs?

Comment: The idea was to write a bpf program which could be configured to only run when called from processes in a certain cgroup. I've since found a better way to accomplish that, however.